# separate group array based on datetime diff

Tags: php, date, time

I want time slot as "FROM DATE" AND "To DATE" from this following array.

basically i want to check if there is 2 Hour Gap then Create New Group as From Date And TO Date.

```
         $finaltime = array();
        for($i=0; $i<count($timeslots);$i++){

            $startdate = $timeslots[$i];

            $result_set = $this->Calendar_model->AllEventTimeSlot($user,$startdate,$conver_end_date);
            echo $result_set;
            if($result_set == 0){
                $finaltime[] = $timeslots[$i];
            }

        }

I have an array as follows:

Array
(
    [0] => 2019-04-01 00:00:00
    [1] => 2019-04-07 06:00:00
    [2] => 2019-04-07 08:00:00
    [3] => 2019-04-07 10:00:00
    [4] => 2019-04-07 12:00:00
    [5] => 2019-04-07 14:00:00
    [6] => 2019-04-07 16:00:00
    [7] => 2019-04-07 18:00:00
    [8] => 2019-04-07 20:00:00
    [9] => 2019-04-07 22:00:00
    [10] => 2019-04-08 00:00:00
    [11] => 2019-04-08 02:00:00
    [12] => 2019-04-08 04:00:00
    [13] => 2019-04-08 06:00:00
    [14] => 2019-04-08 08:00:00
    [15] => 2019-04-08 10:00:00
    [16] => 2019-04-08 12:00:00
    [17] => 2019-04-08 14:00:00
    [18] => 2019-04-08 16:00:00
    [19] => 2019-04-08 18:00:00
    [20] => 2019-04-08 20:00:00
    [21] => 2019-04-08 22:00:00
)
```

Expected Result :

[0] => 2019-04-01 00:00:00   ignore this because not in 2 hour slot .

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [formdate] => 2019-04-07 06:00:00
            [todate] => 2019-04-07 06:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [formdate] => 2019-04-07 10:00:00
            [todate] => 2019-04-07 12:00:00
        )

)
                    ... and soo on
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: To help you with your specific problem we need additional details that highlight exactly where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to use the DateTime Object in PHP.

```
$finaltime = [];
foreach($timeslots as $key => $value){
    //check for another date in the future to compare with
    if(isset($timeslots[$key+1])){
        $start = new DateTime($value);
        $end = new DateTime($timeslots[$key+1]);
        $diff  = $start->diff($end);
        // I've excluded seconds so just checking for 2 hours and 0 minutes
        if($diff->format("%H:%I") == "02:00"){
            $finaltime[] = ['fromdate' => $value, 'todate' => $timeslots[$key+1]];
        }
    }
}
```

If you are comparing different dates then you will need to expand this `$diff->format("%H:%I")` to include days difference too.

Otherwise 2019-08-01 06:00:00 would match with 2019-08-02 08:00:00